# Ubuntu partitioning and hashing

Tags: partitioning, hash

I need to split up Ubuntu in **two partitions**: one partition that contains all the files that do **not** change over time, for instance because of changes in the **date/time** and **logins**, and another partition that contains all those files that might actually change over time. To check that the first partition’s hashing (signature) stays the same (i.e. it does not change over time), I am required to use a hashing algorithm like **MD5** or **SHA1**.

Questions:

1. How to determine what directories/files in the filesystem to include in each partition ?
2. Steps to do this partitioning, provided that Ubuntu keeps working as usual ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: But having parts like /usr on a read-only medium prevents you from running updates etc. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: it's a regulatory requirement, so it's something I need to comply with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux in general is moving slowly towards a system where `/` can be mounted as "read-only" and other partitions can be mounted as "writable".

This move is done by moving things into directories with "run" as a sub directory. Those are "writable". When you look at `df -h` you will see a few of these already:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5,8G     0  5,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,2G  9,5M  1,2G   1% /run
/dev/sda2        46G  8,1G   36G  19% /
tmpfs           5,9G   31M  5,8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5,9G     0  5,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        47M  3,6M   43M   8% /boot/efi
/dev/sda5        34G   11G   22G  34% /home
/dev/sdb1       917G  235G  636G  27% /discworld
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           1,2G   76K  1,2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

As another measure these are (often) mounted as a temporary filesystem (tmpfs).

---

Now to get to the point.

As files at the moment are not defined by being writable or not they are scattered all over the filesystem.

Following the FHS and sticking to the main directories:

- `/bin`, `/lib`, `/sbin` and `/usr` can be mounted read-only.
- `/etc`, `/home`, `/srv`, `/tmp`, `/var` must be writable.
- `/dev`, `/proc`, `/selinux` and `/sys` are handled by special filesystems.

---

[Readonlyroot](https://wiki.debian.org/ReadonlyRoot) on Debian pages has a more indepth article on specific files that prevent a directory from being read-only. For instance `/etc/` is pretty much a mess in regards to getting it separated into read-only and writable files.

---

The command at the end of the link only works for `zsh`.  In chat @serg came up with this as an alternative:

```
{ lsof +L1; lsof|sed -n '/SYSV/d; /DEL\|(path /p;' ; } |grep -Ev '/(dev|home|tmp|var)'
```

---

This command list processes that are open:

```
lsof /
```

And here is a filter to only show the process ids that prevent you to mount as read-only:

```
lsof -F pa /home | awk '/^p/ {pid = substr($0, 2)} /^a.*w/ {print pid}'
```

[Gilles came up with that last one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42083/10017) so upvote his answer :)

Comment: Hi Rindwind ! thanks for your great explanation. if you do not mind, could you let me know the link of the article I need to read from Debian pages ?

Comment: @ekremer that is already a link in the answer ;-) (click the "readonlyroot"